# There is no bottom scroll bar in phpmyadmin 4.1

Tags: phpmyadmin

The scroll bar at the bottom of the page has disappeared in the latest version of Chrome when using `phpmyadmin 4.1.0`. As you can see my table is larger than the screen but there is no scroll bar.

There used to be one in `phpmyadmin  4.0.9`. image is visible here
[image]
The same happens in the latest version of FireFox and also IE 11.

**ANSWER!**

The scroll bar has now been moved to the bottom of the result window instead of at the bottom of the browser window as in every other version of PHPMyAdmin.

View it here
[image]

Comment: Do you know if there's an option to change it back to the old style?

Comment: Looks like they have fixed it in the new release!

Answer (score 0):

They have now fixed it! Thank goodness.

Comment: Can you add more informations about when it was fixed ? from which version ?

Comment: I cannot. It was however the next version on.

Comment: What does it meant that they "fixed" it? The question doesn't imply that anything was broken. What changed? In the latest PhpMyAdmin, the horizontal scrollbar is at the bottom of the search result window instead of the bottom of the page, which is absolutely horrendous and makes me want to throw PhpMyAdmin out the window.

Comment: Ah, I see they "fixed" this again, 13 days ago, but there has been no official stable release since then as of yet: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/14029